# express router patch findoneandupdate not working

Tags: mongodb, express, router, patch

I have the following api to handle an update to mongodb:

```
  router.patch('/update/:id', wrapAsync(async function(req) {
    console.log('id: ', req.params.id);
    console.log('req.body: ', req.body);
    const result = await db.collection('Whisky'.findOneAndUpdate({
      _id: Archetype.to(req.params.id, ObjectId)
    }, {$set: req.body}, {returnOriginal: false}))
    console.log('result: ',result);
    return { result }
  }))
```

the first 2 console.log has this output:

```
id:  5b0bd25e8da4efd060c4f566
req.body:  { contractAddress: '0xd69026Bc6703ADbC1F571D6FBf07eF4a8e33fA0a' }
```

The call to findoneandupdate doesn't seem to be returning.  I am trying to update the contractAddress field in my mongodb.  I am not getting to the last console.log statement.  Does anyone have any idea of what I am doing wrong?  The record exists in the database.  I also tried to call fineoneandupdate using JSON.stringify(req.body) but that didn't work either.  Thanks!

Comment: How do you make the PATCH request? I can't find any info on that.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the closing `)` of `collection` method.

Change it from:

```
await db.collection('Whisky'.
```

To:

```
await db.collection('Whisky').
```

Comment: Fresh eyes!  Thanks.  I was pulling my hair out.

Comment: @Bill Glad to help!